# how to run .sql file from SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and i wanted to execute prestored *.sql files in a folder and wanted to run in SSMS.
can it be possible and if possible can somebody please help me to get how can we implement that?

Comment: File >> Open >> File.. >> F5 (execute)

Comment: this i know i wanted to run by passing the filepath of sql file like we did in SQLCMD.

Comment: Thank you very much Viswanathan iyer.
can i have your skype id or gmail address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok If I'm clear with your question.

1. Go to cmd and navigate to the path where you have stored your `.sql` file.
2. In my case I've stored file on desktop with `vish.sql` name.
3. then `sqlcmd -S DALVI1 -d cookbookdb -i vish.sql`

Note (This is my configuration 
DALVI1 is my `ServerName` 
cookbookdb is `database name` 
vish.sql is `filename`)

Modify as per your configuration.
[For More Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/138983/Tip-Run-a-Transact-SQL-Script-SQL-File-From-the-Co)

[image]